# Is there a function in Kusto anonymize a PII string?

Tags: azure-data-explorer

If I have a PII string is there a function in Kusto to sort of mask it (anonymize) in such a way that it will still retain same distribution but there is no way to get back the original value?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use hash() or hash_sha256() functions to map text into irreversible represenation.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query/sha256hashfunction
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query/hashfunction